# Does a dragon's breath count as magic in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Does dragon breath count as magic in Skyrim? I'm wondering if I could reduce its damage with magic resistance or if I strictly need elemental resistances.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, a dragon's breath counts as magic damage, and so will be reduced by both Magic resistance and Fire/Frost resistance.

Comment: And also can be absorbed by wards